# Can providers in Angular2 bind to typescript interfaces?

Tags: angular

Suppose I have an interface A and a class B implements A.
Can I have provide(A, {useClass: B})?

For some reason it's giving me an error saying it cannot find name A even though it's imported. If I used A in a different context, like typing a variable in the same file it has no problems. Does provide explicitly require a class?

Comment: I replaced it with provide(forwardRef(() => A), {useClass: B}) but I get the same error.

Comment: I looked around and found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254952/binding-a-class-to-an-interface